# Как спроектировать CQRS в таком сценарии

Tags: c#, архитектура, проектирование, cqrs

Есть сценарий при котором пользователь просит сгенерировать документы и вернуть на них ссылки на CDN,
вопрос в том реально-ли в таком сценарии реализовать чистый CQRS ?
Ведь получается когда мы в таком сценарии и пишем и возвращаем данные?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень ясно, что вы имеете ввиду под `чистый CQRS`?

Comment: Одна из существующих точек зрения состоит в том, что обработчики команд _могут_ возвращать результат (можно, например, [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/347908/) почитать).